# Specifying region of interest for google earth engine to calculate Jeffries-Matusita separability?

Tags: python, google-earth-engine

My objective is to compute Jeffries-Matusita separability using google earth engine python api. I have never worked with ee before, so I am trying to follow [this github.](https://mortcanty.github.io/src/zflgee.html)

In it, to import roi it says:

```
table = ee.FeatureCollection('users/mortcanty/supervisedclassification/train')
trainData = image.sampleRegions(table,['CLASS_ID'])
```

What surprised me here is that the file here has no extension. So I tried to use shp (and only shp,not its supporting files).

However, subsequently when I try to parse 'table' in this function

```
def jmsep(class1,class2,image,table):
# Jeffries-Matusita separability    
    table1 = table.filter(
        ee.Filter.eq('CLASS_ID',str(class1-1)))
    m1 = image.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.mean(),table1)\
              .toArray() 
    s1 = image.toArray() \
         .reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.covariance(),table1)\
         .toArray()
    table2 = table.filter(
        ee.Filter.eq('CLASS_ID',str(class2-1)))
    m2 = image.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.mean(),table2)\
              .toArray()
    s2 = image.toArray() \
        .reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.covariance(),table2,15)\
              .toArray()
    m12 = m1.subtract(m2)  
    m12 = ee.Array([m12.toList()]) # makes 2D matrix  
    s12i = s1.add(s2).divide(2).matrixInverse()
#  first term in Bhattacharyya distance
    B1 = m12.matrixMultiply(
          s12i.matrixMultiply(m12.matrixTranspose())) \
            .divide(8)
    ds1 = s1.matrixDeterminant()
    ds2 = s2.matrixDeterminant() 
    ds12 = s1.add(s2).matrixDeterminant()
#  second term
    B2 = ds12.divide(2).divide(ds1.multiply(ds2).sqrt())\
             .log().divide(2)
    B = ee.Number(B1.add(B2).project([0]).toList().get(0))
#  J-M separability
    return ee.Number(1).subtract(ee.Number(1) \
             .divide(B.exp())) \
             .multiply(2)


a = jmsep(5,9,image,table).getInfo()
```

Gives error:

> Collection asset 'C:\Users\train.shp' not found

I suspect this is due to 'shp' file not being appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the table needs to be on the server side for Earth Engine to be able to use it.

The step prior to this script is to add the .shp as an asset in your Earth Engine user.

If you look at the "Assets" tab, there is a red NEW button.  Here you are able to load your shapefile as a table asset that you can use later in your script.